# What types of notifications can I use in admin-on-rest?

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

I use `import { showNotification as showNotificationAction } from 'admin-on-rest';`
I call it like `showNotification(res.error.message, "warning")` or `showNotification(res.error.message, "info")`. Which other types of messages can I use except info and warning?

Answer (score 3):

This part is still not documented so you'll have to explore the source code: https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/master/src/reducer/admin/notification.js#L8